# Incorrect Syntax Near "-"

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2012

My friends,

I am running code via VBA to insert values into a table in SQL Server. However, the following error occurs: "Incorret Syntax Near" - ". Following all steps pressing F8, the error occurs in "Rs.Open StrRs, Cn". Help me find the error?

```vb
Sub InsertSQL()    

Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim StrCn, StrRs As String
Dim FinalLinha As Long

FinalLinha = Planilha1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

StrCn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Initial Catalog=AdvantechDB; Data Source=WIN-I2US3L4IBGJ\HISTSQLSERVER;User Id=sa;Password=libra*123"

Cn.Open StrCn

For i = 2 To FinalLinha

    ID = Planilha1.Cells(i, 1)
    DataValue = Planilha1.Cells(i, 2)
    Quality = Planilha1.Cells(i, 3)
    TimeStamp = Planilha1.Cells(i, 4)
    TimeStamp2 = Planilha1.Cells(i, 5)

StrRs = "INSERT INTO Data_Backup_Modbus-001:tag001(ID,DataValue,Quality,TimeStamp,TimeStamp2)" & _
        "VALUES('" & ID & "'" & "," & "'" & DataValue & "'" & "," & "'" & Quality & "','" & TimeStamp & "','" & TimeStamp2 & "')"

        Rs.Open StrRs, Cn

        Next i

 Rs.Close
 Cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is you're injecting your values. Stop doing that. You ***need*** to use `Parameters.Add`. If you parametrise your query, then problem you have won't exist; as the data you have will be passed as the right data type.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: What is `Data_Backup_Modbus-001:tag001`? Is that a table name? Typically a qualified table name on SQL Server looks like `[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]`.

Comment: The database name in SQL Server is "AdvantechDB". And the table I want to insert the data into is "Data_Backup_Modbus-001: tag001".

Comment: Ok. Whoever named that table needs to get off whatever they're smoking... and you need to make that `[Data_Back_Modbus-001: tag001]` (**with** the square brackets). There are other problems though, answer is WIP.

Comment: One of your parameters have ' in the value so is breaking the Sql String

Comment: You should never ever name a table like "Data_Back_Modbus-001: tag001" -- that's pure insanity. Stop it. But if you HAVE to have a table with that horrific monstrosity of a name, you MUST enclose it in square brackets every time it's referenced. Hint: don't put dots or periods in table names either. Seriously, look up some naming standards and stick to them.

Comment: @pmbAustin to be fair the naming is likely out of OP's hands. Fully agree on the insanity of it though.

Comment: I am using a device that when connecting to SQL Server automatically creates a table in my database. I agree with the insanity of this name. Better to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `-` in what appears to be the table name, is what's causing the problem you're seeing - but there are other issues in the SQL statement itself, and you will absolutely want to address them.

Delete your `StrRs` declaration and assignment.

Then have a local `Const`, and use `[` and `]` characters to delimit *quoted identifiers* - when your table name isn't a standard `PascalCase` identifier (why would you do this to yourself?!), you *must* quote it in queries (that is, enclose it in square brackets).

Note the space between `)` and `VALUES`:

```vb
Const sql As String = _
    "INSERT INTO [Data_Backup_Modbus-001:tag001](ID,DataValue,Quality,TimeStamp,TimeStamp2) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

The `sql` string will be the same for every row. What's going to change at each iteration, is the values of the *parameters* (each parameter is a literal `?` in the command text, without any quotes or concatenations).

```vb
For i = 2 To FinalLinha
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command '<~ DO NOT declare this "As New"
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    'the fun begins - append parameters in the same order they appear in the command string:
    ID = Planilha1.Cells(i, 1)
    DataValue = Planilha1.Cells(i, 2)
    Quality = Planilha1.Cells(i, 3)
    TimeStamp = Planilha1.Cells(i, 4)
    TimeStamp2 = Planilha1.Cells(i, 5)

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Value:=ID, Type:=adVarChar, Length:=Len(ID), Direction:=adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Value:=DataValue, ...)
    cmd.Parameters.Append ...
    cmd.Parameters.Append ...
    cmd.Parameters.Append ...

    cmd.Execute '<~ note: zero need for any recordset here
Next
```

When you use parameterized commands, you never need to care about single quotes; your code gets much cleaner, and a side effect is that it's also more secure (see Bobby Tables XKCD link above), and as a bonus Mr. O'Connor won't break anything.

---

Watch out here:

> ```vb
> Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection
> Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
> ```

These are *auto-instantiated objects*, and the last thing you want is an object that magically respawns automatically.

If this code doesn't output exactly what you expect, then avoid `As New`:

```vb
Public Sub TestAndWeep()
    Dim foo As New Collection
    foo.Add 42
    Debug.Print foo.Count
    Set foo = Nothing
    Debug.Print foo Is Nothing '<~ expecting True, are you?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My friends,

Problem solved. The table name was the cause of the error "Incorret Syntax Near" - ". There were also other errors in the SQL statements, as mentioned by @Mathieu Guindon. I thank you infinitely for your help.

Below is the result code (Disregard the values as they are random):

```
Sub InsertSQL()

Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim StrCn As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim DateTime As Date

StrCn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Initial Catalog=AdvantechDB; Data Source=WIN-I2US3L4IBGJ\HISTSQLSERVER;User Id=sa;Password=libra*123"

Cn.Open StrCn

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(DataValue, adInteger, adParamInput, Len(DataValue))
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Quality, adInteger, adParamInput, Len(Quality))
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(TimeStamp, adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, Len(TimeStamp))
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(TimeStamp2, adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, Len(TimeStamp2))
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(DateTime, adDBDate, adParamInput, Len(DateTime))

Const sql As String = _
    "INSERT INTO [ufvanta5](DataValue,Quality,TimeStamp,TimeStamp2,DateTime) VALUES(1,32772,1567998000,599147,'2019-10-09 17:30:00')"

Rs.Open sql, Cn

Cn.Close

End Sub
```